# Querying Elastic using NEST does not return any response

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I am indexing the following Document class for indexing:

```
public class DoctorDocument
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Experience { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code for searching the index.

```
 var node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");

        var settings = new ConnectionSettings(
            node,
            defaultIndex: "my-application"
        );

        var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

        var searchResults = client.Search<DoctorDocument>(s => s.From(0)
                                                                .Size(100)
                                                                .Query(q =>
                                                                q.Term(t => t.Name, "Deepak Singhal"))
                                                                );
```

For some reason, searchResults is returning no document, even though there is a name "Deepak Singhal" in the index. Any pointers to why nothing is being returned?

Comment: Please check (and post if you can) your mappings. Keep in mind that the Term query that you use "Matches documents that have fields that contain the search term (NOT analyzed)". That is to say "Deepak Singhal" is not analyzed before being searched. If you are using the default analyzer, try searching "deepak". See here: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Comment: Mappings has the field "name" in small case, under the type - "doctordocument" again in lower case. I am able to see the document source when I query by Id in the browser.

Comment: When you indexed the doc "Deepak Singhal", the default analyzer (that i suppose you use) created 2 tokens "deepak" and "singhal". When searching with the terms query the query string is not analyzed like this. Try the match query "q.match(t => t.Name, "Deepak Singhal")". Now the search query is analyzed and should bring you the result.

Comment: Thanks @Manolis, Match Query Descriptor worked. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Manolis has pointed out in the comment, the Term descriptor does not work well with spaces. MatchQueryDescriptor on the field name worked well for me.

```
var searchResults = client.Search<DoctorDocument>(s => s.From(0)
                                                         .Size(100)
                                                         .Query(q =>
                                                              q.Match(mqd => mqd.OnField("name").Query("Deepak Singhal"))
                                                                ));
```